# Show Image and Data in forwarded JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have to show some data and image in the forwarded JSP

To show data I have set the value in the attribute section

```
request.setAttribute("data", mydata);
```

I have the image in stream (InputStream) and I can save it as a file too but would like to know if there is a better way of streaming it directly to JSP page.

If I save it using the servlet temp directory "javax.servlet.context.tempdir" then I cannot access it either through

```
<img src="location of the file set in attribute section"/>
```

Any preferred way other's have tried?

Using Tomcat 7.0.33/Java 7

Comment: How can this be not a real question. I asked.. some one answered and it solved my problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP doesn't really let you stream images per se, but you could achieve this by piping the data from your `InputStream` to `HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream()`.

You could have a servlet that is mapped to image files, something like...

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ImgServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ImgServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ImgServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And then the servlet class itself can handle the image data stream without having to save it to a file. Something like...

```
class ImgServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String imageName = request.getRequestURI();
        InputStream data = service.lookUpImage(imageName); //whatever
        IOUtils.copy(data, response.getOutputStream()); // Apache Commons IO
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    }
}
```

Then the page could just have regular image tags in it.

Comment: This sounds interesting. But how is ImgServlet serving the image when I am finding it hard to access the image from JSP even when the image is saved in the temp directory

Comment: When you say "I have the image in stream", do you mean that you only have an `InputStream` in your Java code, or are the images already in temp files?

Comment: I have the image in InputStream and I can save it to a file too

Comment: Liked the idea of making an individual call from the JSP to the servlet. Its working for me. Thanks